# Should I report Pedro to the authorities?

Tags: freedom-wars

In *Freedom Wars*, there's a character in the CODE 2 cell block named Pedro who speaks of revolution. The options are to leave the conversation, or report him to the authorities.

I was just penalized 20 additional years on my sentence for not selecting a response within 10 seconds, and am now wondering what would happen if I reported him. Are there any negative repercussions for reporting him? Any positive ones?

Comment: I think I reported him since I was all about toeing the party line, but I don't remember anything significant happening due to that decision.  I'd have to go back and check if that NPC is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pedro is related to one of the gangs out side the prison, and **you need to go along with what he says**, or it will have a negative impact on the game.

> If you report him, people start to like you. However, **his gang will come after you** further down the game story. Also, Pedro survives prison, and gets broken out. **You will meet him again**..

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade :) I have made some edits to your question, mostly just to emphasis certain points relating to what OP had asked. Breaking up text like that can make it a lot easier for people to view, and will prevent some critical response/negative feedback. You will notice I have used bold text, and a spoiler tag has previously been added over plot-specific content. Feel free to hit *edit* again to see how that was all set up, but remember, markdown makes a big difference - if you use it right. :)